# Is it better to use @media in html or stylesheet?

Tags: html, css

Is it better to load media queries "@media" in HTML, like so

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="(max-width: 800px)" href="example.css" />
```

or inside the CSS Stylesheet itself?

```
@media (max-width: 800px) {
...
}
```

From what I know is that both will load regardless but will only activate if the condition applies. Is there one that is faster and/or preferable?

EDIT: I want to make a global stylesheet for my website and is thinking of separating styles for different pages in different stylesheets and is wondering which one have a faster loading time (using the media in the html or the css stylesheet)

Comment: Its always good to keep it within `stylesheets` and this is purely opinion based question which would be voted out to be closed based on above reason..

Answer (score 0):

Its always good to Keep @media In CSS.

Using in HTML You can also have different stylesheets for different media:

Comment: Is one faster than the other?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are trying to see the difference between an Internal and External CSS Stylesheet

Internal CSS Stylesheet

```
<head>
   <style type="text/css">
    @media (max-width: 800px) {
    ...
    }
   </style>
 </head>
```

External CSS Stylesheet

```
 <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/support/style.css" />
 </head>
```

Internal and external CSS should be considered in creating a website. Thus, it will affect your page speed.

You might need to read the recommendation from googleinsight:

https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/OptimizeCSSDelivery

Comment: Actually I am not deciding internal or external CSS Stylesheet. I am actually thinking of creating a global stylesheet for my website and am thinking of adding another stylesheet and wanting to separate @media queries in a separate stylesheet and would like to know whether using the queries inside the same stylesheet or in a different one will affect load time

Comment: @william .. Of course, it will affect the load time.. The more global files you have the greater amount of time to buffer. As much as possible, you should you smaller number of files for it will surely affect. This is based on my experience in speeding of my website. Also, you can check this out: http://dyn.com/blog/how-we-improved-page-speed-by-cleaning-css-html-and-images/

Answer (score 0):

CSS purely based on code maintainability and robust implementation. Imagine if you wanted to do the following:

```
@media (max-width:768px) {
    .bob{}
}
```

for 40 elements with class of bob - outside a stylesheet this would be awful to deal with.